# How do I set the scala sdk using gradle in Idea module?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, gradle, ide

My build.gradle file

```
idea {
    project {
        vcs {
            vcs = 'Git'
        }

        jdkName = '1.8'
        languageLevel = '1.8'
    }
}
```

I would also like to set the scala SDK in the module using gradle. 
Right now, I end up having to manually set it from Project Structure in the Idea UI.
Ideally, I would prefer to set it in my build.gradle file such that when I run

> gradle idea

the scala SDK is automatically set for this module

Answer (score 3):

To have a project with scala module in Intellij using gradle,

1. Create a new `IDEA based scala project`
   [image]
2. Give appropriate project name and proceed.
3. Next, check if you've gradle in your local environment. 
   (Install gradle using `$sudo apt install gradle` and then use command `$which gradle` to find location of gradle)
4. Open your terminal and navigate to your project directory. Execute command `$gradle init --type scala-library` 
   This will make your project gradle based and you'll see associated gradle files in Intellij.
5. Restart Intellij and navigate to `View > Tool Windows > Gradle` to see `Gradle` tab.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Gradle documentation for the Scala plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html#sec:scala_dependency_management), you must add the Scala library dependency to the *compile* class path.  For example:

```
compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.4"
compile "org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.12.4"
```

For integration with IntelliJ IDEA, you can apply the idea plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
```

Adding the Scala library to the compile class path is required even if your source is in test code only.  After this, IntelliJ will automatically set up the Scala SDK for you.