# Gradle scala project on intellij

Tags: scala, gradle, intellij-idea

How do we create a new gradle project with scala ? For a maven scala project we had the help of archtypes. What is the similar technique when I change my build script into gradle so that I can get a readymade project structure to go ahead and add my scala files into the project without adding src folders etc.

Comment: Please refer to my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55527630/8574275

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can leverage the [build init plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_init_plugin.html) for this: `gradle init --type scala-library`

This will create a project in the current directory, setup the Gradle wrapper and generate basic build files.

Comment: it worked , but create your project in intellij as scala project to run this plugin

Comment: Add plugin 'idea' and then run 'gradle idea' and it will create the project file.

Comment: Nowadays you should rely on the native import from IntelliJ instead of applying the `idea` plugin.